# Get filtered Rows in excel 2016

Tags: filter, offset, excel-2016

I have used the below formula to dynamically get the rows selected in Excel 2019. but the filter and offset functions are not available in Excel 2016. how can I get the same results using excel 2016?
=FILTER(Data!T7:T114, SUBTOTAL(3, OFFSET(Table2[[#Headers],[Volume (vials)]], ROW(Data!T7:T114) - ROW(Table2[[#Headers],[Volume (vials)]]), 0, 1)))